# BBB: how to turn on Encoder and PWM devices on linux 3.14

Tags: embedded, ubuntu-14.04, beagleboneblack, pwm

I've installed a new image of Ubuntu (14.04.2 LTS) on my **BeagleBone Black** board. I found that cape manager is not supported anymore, so

```
echo bone_eqep2b > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots
```

doesn't work. 
As far as I understood to load device tree overlay I need the following:

1. install RSCM
2. fix `am335x-boneblack.dts` file
3. run build.sh
4. reboot the board

So, I doubt about item 2. How to merge `bone_eqep2b.dts` and `am335x-boneblack.dts` correctly?

I guess, to enable eqep2b I just need to change this block of code:

```
epwmss@48304000 {
        compatible = "ti,am33xx-pwmss";
        reg = <0x48304000 0x10>;
        ti,hwmods = "epwmss2";
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x1>;
        status = "disabled";
        ranges = <0x48304100 0x48304100 0x80 0x48304180 0x48304180 0x80 0x48304200 0x4
8304200 0x80>;

        ecap@48304100 {
                compatible = "ti,am33xx-ecap";
                #pwm-cells = <0x3>;
                reg = <0x48304100 0x80>;
                ti,hwmods = "ecap2";
                status = "disabled";
        };

        ehrpwm@48304200 {
                compatible = "ti,am33xx-ehrpwm";
                #pwm-cells = <0x3>;
                reg = <0x48304200 0x80>;
                ti,hwmods = "ehrpwm2";
                status = "disabled";
        };
};
```

by something like

```
epwmss@48304000 {
        compatible = "ti,am33xx-pwmss";
        reg = <0x48304000 0x10>;
        ti,hwmods = "epwmss2";
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x1>;
        status = "okay";

        count_mode = <0>;  /* 0 - Quadrature mode, normal 90 phase offset cha & chb.  1 - Direction mode.  cha input = clock, chb input = direction */
        swap_inputs = <0>; /* Are channel A and channel B swapped? (0 - no, 1 - yes) */
        invert_qa = <1>;   /* Should we invert the channel A input?  */
        invert_qb = <1>;   /* Should we invert the channel B input? I invert these because my encoder outputs drive transistors that pull down the pins */
        invert_qi = <0>;   /* Should we invert the index input? */
        invert_qs = <0>;   /* Should we invert the strobe input? */

        status = "okay";


        ranges = <0x48304100 0x48304100 0x80 0x48304180 0x48304180 0x80 0x48304200 0x4
8304200 0x80>;

        ecap@48304100 {
                compatible = "ti,am33xx-ecap";
                #pwm-cells = <0x3>;
                reg = <0x48304100 0x80>;
                ti,hwmods = "ecap2";
                status = "okay";
        };

        ehrpwm@48304200 {
                compatible = "ti,am33xx-ehrpwm";
                #pwm-cells = <0x3>;
                reg = <0x48304200 0x80>;
                ti,hwmods = "ehrpwm2";
                status = "okay";
        };
};
```

Correct?

I couldn't find a ready version, It would be great if somebody has already fixed and can share it.

Answer (score 1):

In kernel v3.14 you can enable PWM by setting the status to "okay" for epwmssx, ecapx, & ehrpwmx, under am33xx.dtsi in the dtb-rebuilder project by Robert C Nelson. This, however, will only enable the subsystem and not mux the pins or enable the PWMXTBCLK registers.

To mux the pins for PWM, use "config-pin" from the Universal IO project by cdsteinkuehler on GitHub

To enable the PWMXTBCLK registers, you'll need to write a simple kernel module. (I don't know how to do this in the device tree yet)

*Edit:* Updating outdated references:
In the kernel module you need to write to the following register: `0x44E10664`
This register is also known by name as `CONTROL_MODULE.pwmss_ctrl`

As found on page 796 of *SPRUH73H–October 2011–Revised April 2013* edition of the AM335X Technical Reference Manual, writing 0x01 enables pwm subsystem 1, 0x02 for subsystem 2, 0x04 for subsystem 3, and any combination of the three (for example 0x07 enables all of them: 0x01 | 0x02 | 0x04 = 0x07).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try.

P.S. The more I read about devices in linux, the more I think that the direct writing to the system's registers is a much easier (and better) approach.

Answer (score 1):

I was using kernel 3.18 and to be able to use the eqep modules I have added these to my am335x-bone-common-pinmux.dtsi file to set the pinmux correctly.

```
...
/* eHRPWM0 module */
pinctrl_ehrpwm0: pinctrl_ehrpwm0 {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        0x150 0x23  /* P9_22 = GPIO0_2 = eHRPWM0A, MODE3 */
        0x190 0x21  /* P9_31 = GPIO3_14 = eHRPWM0A, MODE1 */
        0x154 0x23  /* P9_21 = GPIO0_3 = eHRPWM0B, MODE3 */
        /*0x0a4 0x23     This is not OK P8_46 = GPIO2_7 = eHRPWM0B, MODE3 */
    >;
};

/* eCAP0 module ?????*/
pinctrl_ecap0: pinctrl_ecap0 {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        0x164 0x20  /* P9_42A (?) = GPIO0_7 = eCAP0, MODE0 */
    >;
};

/* eQEP0 module */
pinctrl_eqep0: pinctrl_eqep0 {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        0x1a8 0x21  /* P9_41B = GPIO3_20 = eQEP0_index, MODE1 */
        0x1ac 0x21  /* P9_25 = GPIO3_21 = eQEP0_strobe, MODE1 */
        0x1a4 0x31  /* P9_27 = GPIO3_19 = eQEP0B_in, MODE1 */
        0x1a0 0x31  /* P9_42B = GPIO3_18 = eQEP0A_in, MODE1 */
    >;
};


/* eHRPWM1 module */
pinctrl_ehrpwm1: pinctrl_ehrpwm1 {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        0x048 0x26  /* P9_14 = GPIO1_18 = eHRPWM1A, MODE6 */
        0x0c8 0x22  /* P8_36 = GPIO2_16 = eHRPWM1A, MODE2 */
        0x04c 0x26  /* P9_16 = GPIO1_19 = eHRPWM1B, MODE6 */
        0x0cc 0x22  /* P8_34 = GPIO2_17 = eHRPWM1B, MODE2 */
    >;
};

/* eQEP1 module */
pinctrl_eqep1: pinctrl_eqep1 {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        /*0x0d8 0x22     P8_31 = GPIO0_10 = eQEP1_index, MODE2, USED FOR PHOTOCELLS */
        /*0x0dc 0x22     P8_32 = GPIO0_11 = eQEP1_strobe, MODE2 USED FOR PHOTOCELLS */
        0x0d4 0x32  /* P8_33 = GPIO0_09 = eQEP1B_in, MODE2 */
        0x0d0 0x32  /* P8_35 = GPIO0_08 = eQEP1A_in, MODE2 */
    >;
};


/* eHRPWM2 module */
pinctrl_ehrpwm2: pinctrl_ehrpwm2 {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        0x020 0x24  /* P8_19 = GPIO0_22 = eHRPWM2A, MODE4*/
        0x0a0 0x23  /* P8_45 = GPIO2_6 = eHRPWM2A, MODE3 */
        0x024 0x24  /* P8_13 = GPIO0_23 = eHRPWM2B, MODE4 */
        0x0a4 0x23  /* P8_46 = GPIO2_7 = eHRPWM2B, MODE3 */
    >;
};

/* eCAP2 module */
pinctrl_ecap2: pinctrl_ecap2 {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        0x19c 0x24  /* P9_28 = GPIO3_17 = eCAP2, MODE4 */
    >;
};

/* eQEP2 module */
pinctrl_eqep2: pinctrl_eqep2 {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        0x038 0x0F  /* P8_16 = GPIO1_14 = eQEP2_index, MODE4 --- STOLEN FOR MOTOR DIRECTION, ORIGINAL HEX value was 0x24*/
        0x03c 0x0F  /* P8_15 = GPIO1_15 = eQEP2_strobe, MODE4 --- STOLEN FOR MOTOR DIRECTION, ORIGINAL HEX value was 0x24*/
        0x034 0x34  /* P8_11 = GPIO1_13 = eQEP2B_in, MODE4 */
        0x030 0x34  /* P8_12 = GPIO1_12 = eQEP2A_in, MODE4 */
    >;
};
...
```

then also in the am33x.dtsi:

```
    epwmss0: epwmss@48300000 {
        compatible = "ti,am33xx-pwmss";
        reg = <0x48300000 0x10>;
        ti,hwmods = "epwmss0";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        status = "disabled";
        ranges = <0x48300100 0x48300100 0x80   /* ECAP */
              0x48300180 0x48300180 0x80   /* EQEP */
              0x48300200 0x48300200 0x80>; /* EHRPWM */

        ecap0: ecap@48300100 {
            compatible = "ti,am33xx-ecap";
            #pwm-cells = <3>;
            reg = <0x48300100 0x80>;
            interrupts = <31>;
            interrupt-names = "ecap0";
            ti,hwmods = "ecap0";
            status = "disabled";
        };

        eqep0: eqep@48300180 {
            /* pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_eqep0>;*/
            compatible = "ti,am33xx-eqep";
            reg = <0x48300180 0x80>;
            ti,hwmods = "eqep0";
            interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
            interrupts = <79>;
            status = "disabled";
        };


        ehrpwm0: ehrpwm@48300200 {
            compatible = "ti,am33xx-ehrpwm";
            #pwm-cells = <3>;
            reg = <0x48300200 0x80>;
            ti,hwmods = "ehrpwm0";
            status = "disabled";
        };
    };

    epwmss1: epwmss@48302000 {
        compatible = "ti,am33xx-pwmss";
        reg = <0x48302000 0x10>;
        ti,hwmods = "epwmss1";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        status = "okay";
        ranges = <0x48302100 0x48302100 0x80   /* ECAP */
              0x48302180 0x48302180 0x80   /* EQEP */
              0x48302200 0x48302200 0x80>; /* EHRPWM */

        ecap1: ecap@48302100 {
            compatible = "ti,am33xx-ecap";
            #pwm-cells = <3>;
            reg = <0x48302100 0x80>;
            interrupts = <47>;
            interrupt-names = "ecap1";
            ti,hwmods = "ecap1";
            status = "disabled";
        };

        eqep1: eqep@48302180 {
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_eqep1>;
            compatible = "ti,am33xx-eqep";
            reg = <0x48302180 0x80>;
            ti,hwmods = "eqep1";
            interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
            interrupts = <88>;
            status = "okay";
        };


        ehrpwm1: ehrpwm@48302200 {
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_ehrpwm1>;
            compatible = "ti,am33xx-ehrpwm";
            #pwm-cells = <3>;
            reg = <0x48302200 0x80>;
            ti,hwmods = "ehrpwm1";
            status = "okay";
        };
    };

    epwmss2: epwmss@48304000 {
        compatible = "ti,am33xx-pwmss";
        reg = <0x48304000 0x10>;
        ti,hwmods = "epwmss2";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        status = "okay";
        ranges = <0x48304100 0x48304100 0x80   /* ECAP */
              0x48304180 0x48304180 0x80   /* EQEP */
              0x48304200 0x48304200 0x80>; /* EHRPWM */

        ecap2: ecap@48304100 {
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_ecap2>;
            compatible = "ti,am33xx-ecap";
            #pwm-cells = <3>;
            reg = <0x48304100 0x80>;
            interrupts = <61>;
            interrupt-names = "ecap2";
            ti,hwmods = "ecap2";
            status = "okay";
        };

        eqep2: eqep@48304180 {
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_eqep2>;
            compatible = "ti,am33xx-eqep";
            reg = <0x48304180 0x80>;
            ti,hwmods = "eqep2";
            interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
            interrupts = <89>;
            status = "okay";
        };

        ehrpwm2: ehrpwm@48304200 {
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_ehrpwm2>;
            compatible = "ti,am33xx-ehrpwm";
            #pwm-cells = <3>;
            reg = <0x48304200 0x80>;
            ti,hwmods = "ehrpwm2";
            status = "okay";
        };
    };
```

I rebuilt the am335x-boneblack.dtb and copied to the BBB. After this I loaded the eqep kernel module from https://github.com/Teknoman117/beaglebot/tree/master/encoders
 and it works fine.